# PHP + Remove files with .log Extension

Tags: php

I have a folder with an ever growing list of .log files.
Whats a quick way to remove all *.log files from a folder using PHP?

thankyou

Comment: unlink()... thats what I needed... wasn't sure where to start... thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With system access

`system("rm -rf *.log");`

without

just loop through the directory doing a simple unlink if *.log was found.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the logger to prepend date 2012-01-18 to the file, then create a function to check your log directory and remove any logs older than x days.

Comment: or just use the file stamp date.